# Where would the code produced by the JIT would reside

Tags: c#, .net, clr

An article from CLR via C# by Jeffery Ritcher.
"When
calling a virtual instance method, the JIT compiler produces some additional code in the method,
which will be executed each time the method is invoked. This code will first look in the variable being
used to make the call and then follow the address to the calling object."

My question is where would the additional code generated by JIT would reside.

Answer (score 1):

The JIT compiler uses an internal code heap from which to allocate memory to store the generated code. Ultimately, the code heap manager uses the [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) function to allocate memory.